# Partial Fraction Decomposition??

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals, fractions, partial-fractions

How do I separate this by partial fraction decomposition?

$$\int\frac1{u(u^2 + 1)}du$$

I've used the normal technique and got to:

$$1 = A(u^2 + 1) + B(u)$$

and $A=1$ if $u=0$ BUT how do I find $B$ now? because I can't make $u^2 +1$ equal to 0.

Comment: $$\frac{1}{u^2+1}=\frac{i}{2(u+i)}-\frac{i}{2(u-i)}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Patial fractions work when you want to split $$\frac{1}{P(x)Q(x)}$$

into $$\frac{A}{P(X)} + \frac{B}{Q(X)}$$

where $P$ and $Q$ are polynomials.

You don't have that. You have just one polynomial in the denominator.

---

**Hint**:

To calculate the integral, review the derivatives of the basic trigonometric functions and their inverses.

---

**AFTER YOUR EDIT:**

You made a mistake where if the denominator polynomial has degree $n$, then the numerator needs to have degree $n-1$, so in your case, you should set

$$\frac{1}{u(u^2+1)} = \frac Au + \frac{Bu + C}{u^2+1}$$

Now it should be easy to get the solution.

Comment: It is 1/u(u^2 +1) so there are 2 functions in the denominator (it was my error, I've just edited the Q)

Comment: @MATHSHELPNEEDED I edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you. So when u = 0 I get A=1 but what can I make u equal to, to get B and C? ..... I used a random value e.g. 2 but now I have an equation with 2 unknowns (B and C)

Comment: @MATHSHELPNEEDED You get the equation $1=(A+B)u^2 + Cu + A$, correct?

Comment: @MATHSHELPNEEDED You can either set $u$ to another value (say, $1$), to get a third equation, or you can use the fact that two polynomials are equal *if and only if* all their coefficients are equal.

Comment: Yep got it now! :D

Answer (score 0):

The real partial fraction decomposition of $ \frac{1}{u^2+1}$ is $ \frac{1}{u^2+1}$ , since $u^2+1$ has no real zeroes.

We have $u^2+1=(u-i)(u+i)$. For the complex partial fraction decomposition determine $A$ and $B$ such that

$ \frac{1}{u^2+1}= \frac{A}{u-i}+\frac{B}{u+i}$.

But do not use this decomposition for $\int \frac{1}{u^2+1} du$, since

$\int \frac{1}{u^2+1} du=\arctan (u) +C$

Comment: It is 1/u(u^2 +1) so there are 2 functions in the denominator (it was my error, I've just edited the Q)

Answer (score 0):

**Solution without partial Decomposition::**

$$I = \int\frac{1}{u(u^2+1)}du = \int\frac{1}{u^3(1+u^{-2})}du$$

Now Put $1+u^{-2} = t\;,$ Then $\displaystyle -\frac{2}{u^3}du = dt\Rightarrow \frac{1}{u^3}du = -\frac{1}{2}dt$

So $$I = -\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{1}{t}dt = -\frac{1}{2}\ln t+\mathcal{C} = -\frac{1}{2}\ln \left|\frac{1+u^2}{u^2}\right|+\mathcal{C}=\frac{1}{2}\ln \left|\frac{u^2}{1+u^2}\right|+\mathcal{C}$$